# Can anyone tell me how this Recursion method works?

Tags: java, recursion

```
public class Recursion
{
    public static int mystery(int n)
    {
        if(n>0)
        {
            return (n+1)*mystery(n-2);
        }
        else
        {
            return 1;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int x;
        x = mystery(5);
        System.out.println(x);
    }
}
```

I am a newbie in Java. Now, this prints out 48. But, can someone tell me how it is exactly getting to that? Like, I want to know every step it's doing.

Comment: Step through your code with debugger and you will see how things work. When you will see something which you don't understand ask about this specific part.

Comment: Do you understand recursion. For example have you done it with the [Fibonacci series](http://www.programmingsimplified.com/c-program-generate-fibonacci-series)? You're right that this is hard to read, that is one the reasons iterating (loops) are better than recursion in java.

Comment: @NathanCooper Besides the fact that recursion is language independent (meaning "in java" is 100% wrong), iteration is neither better nor worse than recursion - its different, and your statement is a gross characterization. Try solving the Tower of Hanoi with iteration in ANY language.

Comment: m(5) == 6*m(3) == 6*(4*m(1)) == 6*(4*(2*m(-1))) == 6*4*2*1 == 48

Comment: @DavidGrinberg While java is a Multi-paradigm language, there is a widely accepted style and that is to default to iteration. It's true that some things look better with recursion and not everything can be turned into iteration. Anyway, doesn't matter, just making sure that the OP knows that codee wouldn't pass code review.

Comment: @NathanCooper "widely accepted" by who? (hint: that is an incorrect statement). Do not make such broad, baseless and incorrect statements

Comment: @NathanCooper, you are expressing opinion.

Comment: @NathCooper All recursions *can* be turned into iterations by maintaining the stack as an explicit data structure. You push each new frame onto the stack, and then unwind it manually, performing the relevant operations as you go. And of course, all iterations can be turned into recursions by threading the state through the recursive call. It's worth doing the exercise both ways at least once, if only to convince yourself that there's nothing magical about either iteration or recursion!

Comment: it was part of an exam test i know i know...

Comment: @chrisTaylor Indeed. I just didn't want pedants pointing holding me to that statement for all efficiently calculable mu-recursive algorithms. I think this conversation has gotten out of hand. If people stop replying I'll stop dispensing apparently unwelcome stylistic opinions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you call `mystery()` with `n<=0` it will return 1, in all other cases, it will call itself recursively, so the first call of mystery that will return, will return 1, the one that called it will return next, and so on:

- **mystery(5)** = (5+1) * mystery(5-2) = **6 * mystery(3)**

  - **mystery(3)** = (3+1) * mystery(3-2) = **4 * mystery(1)**

    - **mystery(1)** = (1+1) * mystery(1-2) = **2 * myster(-1)**

      - **mystery(-1)** = **1** // !(n>0)
    - mystery(1) = 2 * *1* = **2**
  - mystery(3) = 4 * *2* = **8**
- mystery(5) = 6 * *8* = **48**

Order of calls: mystery(5), mystery(3), mystery(1), mystery(-1)

Order calls return: mystery(-1), mystery(1), mystery(3), mystery(5)

Answer (score 0):

**

- How it Works:

**

```
//main method

public static void main(String[] args){

iMethod(0);

}

 public int iMethod(int c){

  if(c>=20){
    System.out.println("I finished  with c= "+c);
    return;
  }else if(c<20)
    return iMethod(c=c+5);

 }
```

Entering iMethod with (c=0):

```
1.enter second else if(c<20)

  it will go to iMethod(5) cause c now is 5

2.enter second else if(c<20)

 it will go to iMethod(10) cause c now is 10
```

..

```
3.iMethod(15)

4.enter the first if(c>=20)

 it prints 'I finished with c=20' and then return;
```

**back to the method from which it was actually called**

**[in this example it has been called from public static void (String[] args)]**

actually everytime the method **iMethod** **is calling itself** with a different parameter coming from the return.

see it for example like a tree:

```
               the actually iMethod

                     |
                  called her self
                     |
                  called her self
                     |
                   ......
                   finish somewhere and return;
```